# Insert values to dynamic mysql table without knowing its columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, dynamic, insert

I am trying to build a generic method which its purpose is to insert values to an SQL table

The problem is that the SQL table is known only at runtime.

The method receives a string which specifies the values to be inserted. Because of design problem, this the only parameter it recieves: its signature:

```
public Integer create(String values){}
```

My problem is: How can I write a code in which the method will know what columns it has - in string names?

I am thinking of:

```
Statement s = c.createStatement(); //c is of type Connection
String insert_Q = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + (THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK - HOW TO RETRIEVE COLUMNS??) + " VALUES('" + VALUES    + "');" ;

s.executeUpdate(insert_Q);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL is a declarative language.  For an insert, _you_ tell SQL which columns should receive which values.  Even if you could somehow guess at the internal column order, it could change at any point under the hood.  So, you should figure out what the target columns are.

Comment: @Tim Biegelisen thanks. So you suggesting there is no way to know at runtime which columns I have for a MySQL table?

Comment: You _can_ figure out this information, but the thing is, even if you get a list of column names, you would still need to somehow correlate them to the collections of values to be inserted.  So...you really should figure out the column names and targets before you get to your Java code.

Comment: _"Because of design problem..."_ I guess the problem is there was _no_ design. It's time to change the design. I suggest making this function take a `HashMap` instead of a single String.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the table name

Step 1: Get the number of columns from the table using

```
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'Table_Name'
```

Using this get the total number of columns from the table.

Then you can execute your line of statements.

Comment: You may also want a term for `TABLE_SCHEMA` because if a table of that name exists in more than one schema, you'll get the columns for _all_ the tables of the same name.

Comment: Needing to hit the information schema table to do a simple operation such as an insert is, IMHO, either a code smell or a design smell.

Comment: I assume that scenario occurred because of the initial design, either i think the design to be changed or have to use the information schema.

Comment: *"Needing to hit the information schema table to do a simple operation such as an insert is, IMHO, either a code smell or a design smell"* very much agreed @TimBiegeleisen atleast cache information schema in the application somewhere that often tables do not change.. Still not ideal but better..

Comment: @mahadev kalyan srikanth thanks. How do I incorporate that query to java? By the way, I know the design is problematic. As you can understand - it is an exercise that no one knows how to solve :-(

Comment: @guyr79 can you tell if you have any information about the runtime table? That the runtime table has only one column or more than one?

Comment: If it is only one, as you already know, you can directly use "INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> VALUES(<value returned from the call>)"

If not then use the above schema 

String sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'Schema.Table_Name' "

ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);

Iterating on the resultset you can get the column names and then execute your insert statements.